# Converting Classical Images to Quantum Images using INEQR Technique: Feasibility and Python Implementation?

Tags: python, image-processing, quantum-computing

How to convert a classical image into a quantum image using the INEQR technique? and is it possible using Python?

I'm facing difficulties to convert a classical image into a quantum image.so, I'm expecting some suggestions, on how to convert a classical image into a quantum image and whether is it possible to use Python or not. if possible need the Python implementation code,

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforwa algorithm for **QIMP (Quantum image processing)**. Different quantum gates, namely *CNOT, X (NOT), H (Hadamard), Rotation (θ)* are used for QIMP operations. However the laws of classical pixel representation are governed by quantum image representation and compilation. Quantum greyscale code frequently employs the binary pattern. The **QSMC (Quantum States for M Colors of an Image)** is used for color representation, whereas the **QSNC (Quantum States for N Coordinates of an Image)** is used for coordinates. The **QUALPI** uses polar coordinates for the representation of pixel information in quantum state forms. The **NEQR** is used for the representation of images in color format. The FRQI is used for greyscale image processing, whereas the **NEQR** is used for color image processing.

The laws of classical pixel representation are governed by quantum image representation and compilation. Greyscale color images are processed and retrieved using the **MCQI (Multi-Channel Quantum Images)** technique. When an image becomes more complicated, obtaining pixel coordinate information becomes a time-consuming process. For a three-dimensional image, this technique uses **RGB (Red, Green, and Blue)** color. Color information is encoded via controlled rotation and superposition gates. A controlled phase gate creates the image color.

Pixels in 2- or 3-dimensional coordinates are used to represent classical images. Each pixel has its own address in memory for processing and storage. Each pixel has a pixel value, a color combination value, and an orientation.

First, a greyscale classical image is identified with pixel information. After that, image acquisition has been done, like color coding, pixel information, pixel address, and image frames. Outlier detection, removing unwanted noisy data, and detecting and correcting errors are all achieved through image preprocessing. That is, in image preprocessing, image segmentation is performed to speed up the processing of an image. The color code, pixel information, pixel address, and image frame are transformed in a quantum way by the quantum image acquisition block. Quantum image pre-and post-processing extracts classical pixel information and its relevant information and converts it into quantum mechanics qubits for further quantum image processing. When dealing with complex images, image processing becomes a difficult task.

On a classical computer, such work takes time.  As a result, combining classical and quantum computers is a difficult task. Combining classical physics and quantum physics (a quantum computer has features similar to quantum mechanics) is difficult.